# Getting ARcamera background pixel color at runtime using Vuforia in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, vuforia

I was trying to take pixel color  of what Vuforia ARcamera showing at specific position in Unity. firstly I was trying to capture the screen and get pixel however the interval to get the frame was too long. I need to get the color of specific position on what ARcamera showing as soon as my app detect the target. Is there any suggestion or any way to do that ?

I am using unity with latest vuforia 3.0 .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking is Background Texture Access https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/unity-camera-image-access